# Mongo $geoNear with search text duplicate results

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I have a geoNear aggregation query that also includes a $match which uses $text to search for a keyword. When the word is an exact match to a field in the database I get duplicate results. The 2nd result differs only by Distance. I have tried including the unique option in the query but the 2nd result is unique. Before upgrading to the latest version of the mongo driver changing the field in the index did work. Now moving the field to the top of the index returns the same duplicate results. The field is the highest weight at 32. Any ideas as to why I'm getting a duplicate result with no distance?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and trial and error I found that the search text index order and weight affects this greatly. Unfortunately from our deployment js files to mongo we were not able to set the order of the search text index. I solved this by using a union in lodash. Additionally you must also set the 'unique' option on the $geoNear query.